# Tensorflow ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Timestamp)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

My code uses a csv file of all megasena results.

```
data['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Data'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
features = data[['Data', 'Conc']]
labels = data[['NR1', 'NR2', 'NR3', 'NR4', 'NR5', 'NR6']]

# convert date column to numerical features
features['Day'] = features['Data'].dt.day 
features['Month'] = features['Data'].dt.month 
features['Year'] = features['Data'].dt.year  

# normalize the features (year should have more weightage than day and month)
features['Day'] = features['Day'] / 31.0
features['Month'] = features['Month'] / 12.0
features['Year'] = (features['Year'] - 2000) / 20.0

# split the data into training and testing sets
train_features = features[features['Conc'] <= 2601].values
train_labels = labels[labels.index <= 2601].values
test_features = features[features['Conc'] > 2601].values

# define the model architecture
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, input_shape=[5], activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])
```

The error happens in training, I already tried to solve it by changing the type of day, month and year, to float, np.float32, tf.float32 and none of them solved the problem.

```
# train the model
model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=100)
```

Comment: features , train_features, and test_features are pd.Dataframes so would you print the dtype of each column to check them before passing them to model.fit(), also how did you change the dtype from datetime to float.

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo de Souza Ferreira, The dataset type is not valid for the model training. Please convert the dataset datatype into float using `features['Day'] = features['Day'].astype('float32')`.

Answer (score 0):

the solution found was this converts the date to float and drop the date column

```
features['DataF'] = data['Data'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
features['Day'] = features['Data'].dt.day
features['Month'] = features['Data'].dt.month
features['Year'] = features['Data'].dt.year
features.drop(['Data'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```